# C# importing class as *

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

After building my first big project using C# i ran into a problem.
My project file is about 7000 lines big atm and fillde with functions and other classes.
This is ofcourse a little messy and to find the code that i actually need i sometimes need to scroll around quite a bit so i want to remove all the classes and functions to a different file.
I know i can just add a c# class file and then access it by doing

```
    namespace Namespace
{
    class Functions
    {
        // Example Functions here
    }
}

    namespace OtherNamespace
{
    class OtherClass
    {
        Namespace.Functions.Examplefunction
    }
}
```

If the example function would actually exist that is.
But i would like to get rid of the Namespace.Functions part as it would save me alot of typing and i use these functions often. How would i do that ? Is it even possible?

I know it is achievable in python like this

```
import math as *
```

for example, then you wouldnt have to write

```
math.cos(0)
```

but instead you can just write

```
cos(0)
```

Comment: You can just add `using Namespace;` to your other code files. If you're using C# 6 or later you can use `using static Namespace.Functions;` and then you don't have to reference 'Functions' - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) for more - note that _using static imports only accessible **static** members and nested types declared in the specified type_

Comment: @stuartd thanks for the reply, i know it was a stupid question but i couldnt figure it out... but thanks that fixes it indeed!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a static import feature of C# if you want to use many static helper functions. I've provided a basic example. You can use this for standard .NET framework classes such as `System.Math`, `System.Console` etc.

```cs
namespace Utils 
{
    // using static
    using static Utils.Helper;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // no need to type Helper.Pow(2, 2);
            var x = Pow(2, 2);

            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}

namespace Utils
{
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static double Pow(int x, int pow) => Math.Pow(x, pow);
    }
}
```